# Is there an elegant way to solve this equation without expanding the terms? $[(x+3) + 3][(x + 3)^2 + 3^2] + [(x+1) + 1][(x+1)^2 + 1^2] = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$[(x+3) + 3][(x + 3)^2 + 3^2] + [(x+1) + 1][(x+1)^2 + 1^2] = 0$

$⟺ (x + 6)(x^2 + 6x +18) + (x + 2)(x^2 +2x + 2) = 0$

$⟺ 2(x^3 + 8x^2 + 30x + 56) = 0$

$⟺ 2(x + 4)(x^2 + 4x + 14) = 0$

$⟺ x = -4$

I wondered if a simpler solution exists as there seems to be some structure to the original equation that is not used in the above solution.

Thank you!

Comment: If you can solve the question by expanding, please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4850862/edit) the question and add that approach.

Comment: @DS Thanks! I'll edit my post right now!

Comment: What is the source of the question?

Comment: Anyway, after seeing the question, my thoughts were: The questioner doesn't want the solver to solve a difficult cubic, so integer, or at most fractional roots (no irrational). Also, any root must be negative. So, by RRT, the possible candidates are $-1, -2, -4,$ (other candidates are removed because then both terms would be negative. If these don't work, then $-1/2, -7/2$ are the fractional candidates.

Comment: @DS Oh it's from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAitvHF81J8&list=LL&index=38&t=3s

I solved it using a different approach (by expressing $82$ as $9^2 + 1^2$, moving all terms to the left side, isolating x = 0 as a solution, and being left with the expression posted above. I supposed there is a simpler way to solve the equation above but struggled to figure it out.

Comment: Also, if you set $y = x-4$, it is not hard to see $y=0$ works.

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$(a + b)(a^2 + b^2) = \frac{a^4 - b^4}{a - b}.$$
So, noting first that $x = 0$ is not a solution, the equation given has the equivalent form:
$$\frac{(x + 3)^4 - 3^4}{x} + \frac{(x + 1)^4 - 1^4}{x} = 0,$$
i.e.
$$(x + 3)^4 + (x + 1)^4 = 1^4 + 3^4.$$
From here, we can eyeball a couple of potential solutions, simply by trying to enforce $(x + 3)^4$ and $(x + 1)^4$ to be the two numbers $1^4$ and $3^4$. One such potential solution would be $x = 0$, but this is a false solution we obtained in our first step, multiplying top and bottom by $x$. We could also make $(x + 3)^4$ to be $1^4$ and $(x + 1)^4$ to be $3^4$, exploiting the evenness of the $x \mapsto x^4$ map, by setting $x = -4$.

Are there other real solutions? No, because the map $f(x) = (x + 1)^4 + (x + 3)^4$ is a strictly convex function (a term that may not be appropriate to the given tags). As such, $f(x) = k$, where $k$ is a constant, will have at most two real solutions. Given one was the (false) solution $x = 0$, and the other was $x = -4$, the original equation has only the $x = -4$ solution.